# I can't change the boot order!

Tags: boot, boot-order

I can go and and play with the boot orders all I want but my computer will always read my hard drive first. What do I do to get Ubuntu on my computer?

Computer Info ------>  http://instagram.com/p/hrCjIQLa8a/
Computer Info ------>  http://instagram.com/p/hwJ11WLa8j/

It would be great if someone could help me figure this out!

You guys rock....

Comment: Are you using a DVD or a USB stick? Some computers aren't capabale of booting from stick...

Comment: @the_Seppi I was trying to boot from a DVD.

Comment: Have you tried changing the boot order while DVD inserted? Or hit F12/F2/... on bootup.

Comment: @the_Seppi Yes and yes....

Comment: Can you access the BIOS setup menu? Or try hitting F12 WHILE pressing the power button.

Comment: @the_Seppi I can get into the boot menu just fine but nothing happens when I change the order.

Comment: Maybe there's a update for your BIOS. Check the manufacturers website...

Answer (score 1):

First make sure in BIOS that you have USB option boot-up above Harddrive or simply put HDD all the way down.

Second use unetbootin for writing image into USB stick.

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you I'm trying that now. I puts add. I was watching a YT vid on it and in the vid their Ubuntu file had a cd as the icon and mine was a file.

Comment: It didn't work man!!!

Comment: check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJ5aCgwUG0c) and can you attach photo of your BIOS settings ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to boot from a Live USB. So what you have to do is to plug in your Live USB, then turn the computer on, enter BIOS and check how is your USB stick read/considered by BIOS. Sometimes it is not considered/recognised as a Removable Device but as a Hard Disk Drive, so enter Boot tab and check if your USB is recognised as a HDD, if it is so, then set it as first HDD (place it at the top of the HDD list, 1st. priority). Save and exit.

Comment: So drag and drop the file onto a usb? correct?

Comment: No. you have to "burn" the ISO file to your stick like you did with your DVD. -> www.pendrivelinux.com